# Apache only loading "It works" and not files

Tags: html, apache, virtualhost, markup

I recently had my hard drive cleared and I reinstalled Apache,  I've seen this on other websites but none of the solutions worked for me, Apache keeps display "It works" when I do the root website domain ( http://wrks.tk/ ).  It doesn't display the folders and files within it.

Another problem is that when I try to load my website folders ( http://wrks.tk/DNS ) it gives a 404 Error.

In my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Workarea"
        ServerName wrks.tk
        ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-err"
        CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-acc" common
        <Directory "/Workarea">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the location to everything is correct.

`EDIT 1`

Okay, I located the index.html file in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, it it contained "It works!".  But that doesn't help me much.

`EDIT 2`

I added `DirectoryIndex Home.php` to my virtual host. And then added a `Home.php` to my website, and put some stuff in it, but I still get "It works!".

`EDIT 3`

I Noticed that I couldn't even edit the file name, so I renamed the folder to something else, that didn't work. I also tried making a new folder. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The built in apache isn't really configured out of the box to be used as a development environment.

I find it's best to set `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and everything inside it to be owned by your user account instead of by system (remember to restart apache after making changes).

Then edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and find the user/group and change it from the default value to also run as your user. This is what mine looks like:

```
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User abhi
Group staff
```

Then you can just delete `index.html` and all the other junk that's in there. It's not used for anything.

There are probably a bunch of other things you'll want to change in `httpd.conf`, such as enabling `.htaccess` files to function fully like they can on a typical Linux server. And PHP will need configuration changes too, for example it doesn't show errors by default — a bug in your code will just give you a blank page.

Alternatively... install [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) as it is much easier to work with and has been designed to be used for development, unlike Apple's install of apache.

Comment: Hello, it's still not working, I added "User xero" and "Group staff", but it still prints out "It worksss!", I restarted Apache and everything.

Comment: Okay, so I've ran into another problem, I deleted the index.html, but then it's listing the other two images that were in that folder, I'm gonna go ahead and delete everything in the folder.

Comment: I'm not sure, there must be something configured wrong. If you can't figure it out I suggest trying MAMP.